# Web API - Interceptor - intercepting async controller actions

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

In our Web API integration tests we are having issues with testing the async actions.

In my simple test I created a simple controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("test")]
public async Task<ApiResponse> Test()
{
    return await Task.FromResult(new ApiResponse(true));
}
```

However when I am running the integration tests it fails on the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type
>   'Jacobo.Api.Model.Shared.ApiModels.ApiResponse' to type
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Jacobo.Api.Model.Shared.ApiModels.ApiResponse]'.
>   at Castle.Proxies.IIdentityControllerProxy.Test()    at
>   ServerApi.IntegrationTests.IdentityControllerTests.d__10.MoveNext()
>   in
>   E:\Dev\Jacobo\ServerApi.IntegrationTests\IdentityControllerTests.cs:line
>   218
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   NUnit.Framework.Internal.AsyncInvocationRegion.AsyncTaskInvocationRegion.WaitForPendingOperationsToComplete(Object
>   invocationResult)    at
>   NUnit.Framework.Internal.Commands.TestMethodCommand.RunAsyncTestMethod(TestExecutionContext
>   context)

I can see where this is coming from as we are returning a result which is no longer matching the action return type which is obviously wrapped in a task.

The whole block of our Interceptor code runs fine:

```
public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
{
    // our interceptor implementation ...
    // some irrelevant code before this
    invocation.ReturnValue = webInvocation.Invoke(_client, invocation.Arguments); // the return value is populated correctly. not wrapped in a task.
}
```

and then the test fails as it's trying to return the awaited result:

```
[Test]
public async Task GettingAsyncActionResultWillSucceed()
{
    var ctl = BuildController(new SameMethodStack("GET"));
    var result = await ctl.Test();
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Success);
}
```

I am very unsure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution. I had to detect if the method is async and based on that wrap the result into a task:

```
if (isAsync)
            {
                var result = webInvocation.Invoke(_client, invocation.Arguments);
                var type = result.GetType();
                var methodInfo = typeof(Task).GetMethod("FromResult");
                var genericMethod = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type);
                invocation.ReturnValue = genericMethod.Invoke(result, new []{ result });
            }
```